# ActiveRecord: Querying for parent record where child records have certain values in an AND query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Normally I understand that if you pass an array of values to an ActiveRecord query it executes it like an OR statement. That is to say:

`Parent.joins(:kiddos).where(kiddos: {rando_attr:[1,2]})`

This query looks for `Parent` objects where the parent object has a `kiddo` object that has `rando_attr` of EITHER 1 OR 2.

In my case however, I want to look for `Parent` object where the parent object has a `kiddo` object with `rando_attr` of 1, AND ALSO has a `kiddo` object with `rando_attr` of 2.

How would I write this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rb
Parent.joins(:kiddos)
.where(kiddos: {rando_attr:[1,2]})
.group(:id).having('COUNT(DISTINCT(kiddos.rando_attr)) = 2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the array syntax makes an IN query (which is like a logical or), an alternative to grouping (@Lam's answer) can be using 2 wheres

```
Parent.joins(:kiddos).where(kiddos: {rando_attr: 1}).where(kiddos: {rando_attr: 2})
```

Comment: this was actually my initial approach (trying to use AR only , not pure SQL). I posted this question because this didn't work... no matter what order the `rando_attr` queries were passed, it only worked for the first query. The second query returned a blank array...

Comment: @james hmm that's very bizarre, I can't see why that would happen actually.